# How to send Servlet response using Listner

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing multi-threaded java sevlet having following scenario
Data comes in different chunks and for that I only need to send response in last request.
Data chunk forwarded to other classes for holding  data.

```
public class RequestController extends HttpServlet implements ResponseHandler {
    private ExecutorService pool;
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpServletResponse> cache;

    static {
        cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpServletResponse>();
    }

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try {


            BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
            String msg = br.readLine();
            br.close();

            if (msg == null) {
                msg = request.getParameter("request");
                //return;
            }
            String number = msg.substring(msg.indexOf("//") + 2, msg.indexOf(";"));
            System.out.println("number = " + number);
            cache.put(number, response);
            System.out.println("Request received");
            msg = URLDecoder.decode(msg, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(msg);
            pool.submit(new DuplicaterRequestHandler(msg, this));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

}

This is my servlet code.
cache is a static storage which I am using to send resonse after receiving of all request

I have a listner as well which tells the sevlet that request is completed

```
public interface ResponseHandler {

    public void sendResponse(String number, String data);
}
```

and its implementation in RequestController is

```
 @Override
    public void sendResponse(String number, String data) {

        System.out.print(number);
        System.out.println(cache.containsKey(number));


        if (cache.containsKey(number)) {
            try {
                PrintWriter pr = cache.get(number).getWriter();
                pr.println(data);
                pr.close();
                cache.remove(number);
                System.out.println("response sent.");
                System.out.println("data:" + data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

all is looking good but its throw a exception some time, not every time, which is unknown to me.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:462)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:383)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.IntermediateOutputStream.write(C2BConverter.java:278)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.WriteConvertor.write(C2BConverter.java:242)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.C2BConverter.convert(C2BConverter.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:184)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.print(CoyoteWriter.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.println(CoyoteWriter.java:309)
    at duplicateserver.request.cotroller.RequestController.sendResponse(RequestController.java:132)
    at duplicateserver.request.manager.CallLogRestoreManager.processRequest(CallLogRestoreManager.java:35)
    at duplicateserver.request.handler.DuplicaterRequestHandler.run(DuplicaterRequestHandler.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't rely on the writer objects being available after the request has finished. So if that's what you're trying to do, you have to do it differently.

Comment: Agree but how to do it? any sugession?

Comment: Either, you have to make new requests to your servlet (polling), or maybe websockets, depending on content.

Comment: I am new to servlets, please provide some tutorial links.

Answer (score 2):

> throw a exception some time, not every time

This suggests a thread safety problem to me.

Your servlet has a shared, modifiable cache.  You remove the number from the cache, but I don't see any synchronized blocks to guard against race conditions.

You probably have one thread enter that code after finding the number in the cache.  Another thread comes in and removes the number, so in spite of the fact that the first thread passed the if test the number is gone from the cache when it executes the get.

Make that operation atomic and see if you fare better.

```
@Override
    public void sendResponse(String number, String data) {

        System.out.print(number);
        System.out.println(cache.containsKey(number));

        synchronized(this) {
            if (cache.containsKey(number)) {
                try {
                    PrintWriter pr = cache.get(number).getWriter();
                    pr.println(data);
                    pr.close();
                    cache.remove(number);
                    System.out.println("response sent.");
                    System.out.println("data:" + data);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using ConcurrentHashMap for the storage, thats mean the issue is something with response which throw exception

Comment: I don't think ConcurrentHashMap is enough.  You have to make the if/get/remove atomic.

Comment: It is throwing exception while writing data by pr.println(data)

Comment: Could it be that the writer is null, then?

Comment: I still think it's a threading issue, a race condition.  Why don't you try adding the synchronized block?  It's the right thing to do, no matter what you say.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30459/discussion-between-talha-zubair-and-duffymo)